# Topological Fundamental Group quotient of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}(t)} \vert \mathbb{Q}(t))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about an argument used in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (or look up at page 130):

[image]

Why is $\Pi(n):= \pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1 \backslash \{P_1,..., P_n\})$ a quotient of the profinite Galois group $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}(t)} \vert \mathbb{Q}(t))$?

Comment: For $f\in \overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$ with $K = \Bbb{C}(z,f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ its normal closure then $Gal(K/\Bbb{C}(z))$ is the monodromy group of the locally analytic function $f(z)$ (the coefficients of $\prod_{l=1}^n (Y-f_l)$ stay the same when continued analytically along any curve and at the few isolated singularities they have at most a polynomial growth so they are meromorphic on the Riemann sphere). Let $L$ be the subfield of $\overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$ of functions locally meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}-p_1,\ldots,p_m$. Then $Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z)) =\pi_1(\Bbb{C}-p_1,\ldots,p_m)$

Comment: @reuns: so we start with a  integral proper normal curve $X$ over $k$  and fix an open set $U$. Here $U= X=\mathbb{P}^1-\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$.

Then there exist a category equivalence between category of proper normal
curves $Y$ equipped with a finite separable morphism $φ : Y → X $ etale over $U$ and the category of finite continuous left $π_1(U)$-sets. This boild down to the monodromy-action you described,right? (compare with thm 4.6.4 at p 120 from the source mentioned above). Do you mean it in that way or did I misunderstood your point?

Comment: @reuns: one remark: By $f\in \overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$ you mean the primitive element of $K$?

Comment: I mean any $f \in \overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$. The curve is the Riemann surface of $f$ which is $\{ (z,f_\gamma(z),f_\gamma'(z),\ldots,f_\gamma^{(k)}(z)), z \in \Bbb{C} - p_1,\ldots,p_n, \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ with $k$ large enough so that it doesn't cross itself and $f_\gamma$ are all the analytic continuations of $f$ along homotopy classes of curves $\gamma$ (try with $f(z) = z^{1/2} $ and $z^{1/2}(z-1)^{1/2}$). The (germ of) $f$ can be represented as a function analytic on $\Re(z) \in (0,a)$ or as a Puiseux series at $z=0$.

Comment: @reuns: what do you mean by the neccessarity to take $k$ big enough such that "$\{ (z,f_\gamma(z),f_\gamma'(z),\ldots,f_\gamma^{(k)}(z)), z \in \Bbb{C} - p_1,\ldots,p_n, \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ doesn't cross itself"? I know only that a locally analytic function $f$ induces a Riemann surface via $\{ (z,f_\gamma(z)), z \in \Bbb{C} - p_1,\ldots,p_n, \gamma \in \Gamma\}$. As for example  $log (z)$ or $z^{1/2}$. When in the theory of Riemann surfaces this "crossing phenomena" occure such that the resulting RS has higher derivatives as ""extra data"?

Comment: You need to make clear the difference between curve, smooth curve and Riemann surface. The problem is when $f_\gamma \ne f_{\gamma_2}$ but $(a,f_\gamma(a)) =(a,f_{\gamma_2}(a))$, try with $f(z) = z^{1/2}-(1-z)^{1/2}$ and $a=1/2$. Locally adding more derivatives help to distinguish between $(a,f_\gamma(a)),(a,f_{\gamma_2}(a))$, and it is a theorem in Stein manifolds that globally we need only finitely many derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a Noetherian normal integral scheme with generic point $\eta$ then there is an identification of $\pi_1(X,\overline{\eta})$ with $\mathrm{Gal}(M/k(\eta))$ where $M$ is the compositum of all finite separable extensions $L/k(\eta)$ such that the normalization $Y$ of $X$ in $L$ is a finite etale cover $Y\to X$. In particular, since $M$ is Galois (as can be easily checked) you deduce that $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k(\eta)}/k(\eta))$ surjects on to $\pi_1(X,\overline{\eta})$.

In your case note $X=\mathbb{P}^1-\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ is normal and $k(\eta)=\mathbb{Q}(t)$.